# Are there Data Transfer Charges for using Public Data Sets in Amazon AWS?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Basically, I'm in a free tier with my single t1.micro instance. I want to use the Wikipedia dump file public data set.

Would Amazon charge me if I'm processing some 2-4 GB of data in my instance from that dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Any data into AWS network is free , it will be charged if your data is moving out from AWS network

Comment: So what you're saying is, if I fetch data from the aws datasets, process them and just keep it in my instance, I won't be charged.

But, if I try to transfer results to my computer or display it in an html document, it will be charged (technically).

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a public dataset, you need to create an EBS snapshot with the corresponding volume and attach it to your instance. SO you will be charged against your storage when using an AWS public dataset as your EBS volume will count, if I'm not mistaken.

The way I see it, Amazon is simply hosting the full datasets on their servers, but if you want to use them you will most likely be charged because you're using EBS as your storage.

[source](http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets/)

Comment: Things have changed a bit.  In 2017, many public datasets are on s3 and those have nothing to do with EBS.